MD_Parola.h MD_MAX72xx.h 8x8 led Matrix only lighting up rows when animating
I am attempting to build out my first custom 8x8 led matrix.
My hardware currently is a arduino nano esp32 and max7219CNG chip for led control.
My issues is that the animation is lighting up a full column and running it right to left in a split second, almost as if this MX_Parola is interpreting my 8x8 matrix as its own single pixel in a larger scheme rather than addressing the individual LED as a pixel in this scheme.
I have everything wired up according to the below diagram.

Leveraging this test code:

#include <MD_Parola.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>

#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::GENERIC_HW
#define MAX_DEVICES 1 // 4 blocks
#define CS_PIN D10 // The Arduino Nano ESP32 pin connected to the CS pin of the LED matrix
// #define DATA_PIN D11
// #define CLK_PIN D13
// create an instance of the MD_Parola class
MD_Parola ledMatrix = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, CS_PIN,MAX_DEVICES);

void setup() {
  ledMatrix.begin();         // initialize the object
  ledMatrix.setIntensity(0); // set the brightness of the LED matrix display (from 0 to 15)
  ledMatrix.displayClear();  // clear led matrix display

  ledMatrix.displayText("Hello", PA_CENTER, PA_SCROLL_LEFT, 1000 ,PA_SLICE);
}

void loop() {
  if (ledMatrix.displayAnimate()) {
    ledMatrix.displayReset();
  }
}


I have tried rotating the MAX7219 chip 180 degrees in my setup, expecting to resolve the problem. What actually happened was 2 center leds were lit but no others while running the same code.

-I cycled through #define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::GENERIC_HW options. it resulted in different timing of the same animation.
